# Java Beginner matching program not building

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to Java and don't understand why I receive an error when I build this specific program below. Any tips/advice will be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Swipe {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Yes or No?");
    boolean yes = sc.nextBoolean();
    if (yes) {
        System.out.println("Congrats!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No match :(");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which platform are you using? And can you paste the errors you are getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hmatar Also, I'm using NetBeans!

Comment: @hmatar this is the error I receive when making the build.. ( Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1782) at swipe.Swipe.main(Swipe.java:18)

Comment: @dfili8 I have tested your program and put my answer as below.

Answer (score 2):

`sc.nextBoolean();` accept a boolean `true` and `false` and not `Yes` or `No`, so instead of using this message **Yes or No?**, I suggest to change it to **true or false?**.

---

Or another Option if you want to use **Yes** or **No** you have to use a `String` instead like this :

```
String yes = sc.nextLine();
if (yes.equals("Yes")) {
    System.out.println("Congrats!");
} else {
    System.out.println("No match :(");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program crashes because you are entering `"Yes"` which can not be converted to `True` Java data type by `nextBoolean()` method. The same goes for `"No"`.

**Solution:** Always enter `True` or `true` for `"Yes"`, and `False` or `false` for `"No"`. I tried this and it works on my machine.

**As an alternative solution**, you can use @YCF_L's approach where your read `"Yes"` and `"No"` as strings and check accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Worked on my machine as well!